# Rails migration, change :id column type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-migrations

How I should change the following code for use `:id` column as primary key, with `auto_increment` and `:limit => 8`

```
def change
  create_table :companies, :id => false do |t|
    t.integer :id, :limit => 8
    t.string :name

    t.timestamps
  end
end
```

This code does not made `:id` column as primary key and does not create sequence for auto increment.

PostgreSQL 8.4, Rails 3.2.11

Comment: What is `limit` in this context?

Comment: I need :id column as bigint. (:limit=>8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing a column's length or datatype in a migration will invalidate the column as a primary key. Rather, creating an initializer that overrides the site's default primary key datatype should provide the behavior you're looking to implement:

```
# config/initializers/change_primary_key_datatype.rb
require 'active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter'
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter::NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES[:primary_key] = "bigserial primary key"
```

Remember to restart the server after saving the initializer.

Comment: It works, but problem is: I need bigint as primary key only for one table.

Comment: Ahh. However, my answer addresses your original question, which doesn't specify whether the change should apply to every table or a single one. As such, if this answer has worked, it would be helpful for other readers if you marked as accepted by clicking the check mark.

Comment: To follow up on your particulary situation: I don't believe that it's possible to make Rails behave in the manner you've depicted. Primary keys in Rails can be set application-wide for each adapter, but any modification to a primary key's datatype in a migration will necessarily negate that column acting as a primary key.

Comment: This is sad. Thank you for advise.